# Database column mixed content type

Tags: database, oop, database-design

I have an object property that accepts either a `string` value, a `bool`or a `float`.

I chose to implement this as a string value along with a type automatically set by the system when the user calls the overloaded methods to set the value of the property `setValue(float)`, `setValue(bool)` or `setValue(String)`.

In the database i have only one column representing the value. I also save the type as well.

What alternative solution would you recommend? I don't want to create *boolean_value*, *float_value*, *string_value* properties to accommodate the different scenario I may face.

Comment: Why don't you save them all as string? They should be easily converted to any type when retreived.

Answer (score 3):

I think the 3 values are conceptually different. 
If I where facing the problem, I would have three different fields on the database level.
Regarding to [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (`each attribute contains only atomic values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain`.) 
Soon or late you will need calculation on the float value or comparison on bool value, having them separated will help a lot and the data module will be illustrative.

Comment: +1 for three different fields. Place a constraint in the database and/or application to ensure that only one of them can have a value, optionally including another column to indicate which one is expected to be populated.

Answer (score 2):

There should be only one true value; store this value in the database using the least common denominator, yet still satisfies all possible values (e.g. if the value is "true" vs "false", then use a boolean). Perform type juggling in application layer. Understanding the [Single Source of Truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth) theory may help your design decision.

If you are storing it in the database for caching purposes, then it makes more sense to store all 3 types - no sense in wasting cycles converting if performance is king.